# Adding a record to an access database, Where is the error in this code?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, insert

read a lot about DataAdapter, DataTable ,.. to reach to this code, in the Save Button:

```
'insert new row
ds.Tables("Employees").Rows.Add(ENumTxt.Text, ENameTxt.Text, EPosTxt.Text,  
  EAgeTxt.Text, ESalTxt.Text, EPhonTxt.Text, EAdrsTxt.Text)
'save changes
ds.AcceptChanges()
Try
  If ds.HasChanges Then
    Dim AffectedDS As DataSet = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
    'im ComBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    da.InsertCommand = ComBuilder.GetInsertCommand
    da.Update(AffectedDS, "Employees")
  End If
Catch e1 As OleDb.OleDbException
  MessageBox.Show(e1.Message)
End Try
```

===============================================================================
Then I tried this:

```
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
' Insert a new record in the DataSet
Dim r As DataRow = ds.Tables("Employees").NewRow()
r("EID") = ENumTxt.Text
r("EName") = ENameTxt.Text
r("Age") = EAgeTxt.Text
r("Salary") = ESalTxt.Text
r("EPhone") = EPhonTxt.Text
r("EAddress") = EAdrsTxt.Text
ds.Tables("Employees").Rows.Add(r)

' Insert the record even in the database
da.Update(ds.Tables("Employees").GetChanges())
' Align in-memory data with the data source ones
ds.AcceptChanges()
```

==========

In run time, i got the same error message for both cases

```
"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"
```

Please give me some guidlines to fix this error.

Comment: Please reformat your code and make your problem clearer. Help us help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther error is in your INSERT statement, as the error says ...

How does the INSERT statement that has been specified by the 'InsertCommand' of your DataAdapter look like ?

Comment: I thought about that, but i could not reach it, how can i check the INSERT statement ?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is if using the Commandbuilder, does your table have a primary key defined?

Comment: Yes, the EID is the primary key.